# Solving an inexact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the ODE:   $y'=\frac{2x^2y-xy^2+0.5y^2}{x^2-xy+y-1}$
Given that $M(x,y) = -2x^2y+xy^2-0.5y^2$ and $N(x,y)= x^2-xy+y-1$ , $N_x \neq M_y$ , I've been trying to look for an integration factor to make this ODE an exact one.
The Integration factor I've found is: $ \mu(x) = \frac {e^{-2x+2}}{(x-1)^2}$ But that dosen't make the ODE exact. I've triple checked my way of solving and I can't find any reason to that error.
I did try finding an integration factor for the variable $y$ but that doesn't solve it either.

My way of finding the integration factor:

$ \frac{M_y-N_x}{N(x,y)} = \frac{-2x^2+2xy-y-(2x-y)}{x^2-xy+y-1} =\frac{-2x^2+2xy-2x}{x^2-xy+y-1} = \frac{-2x(x-y+1)}{(x-1)(x-y+1)} = \frac{-2x}{x-1}$

$ \mu(x)  = e^{\int\frac{-2x}{x-1}dx} $  $=  e^{-2x+2-2\ln(x-1)}  = e^{-2x+2} \cdot \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}  $

Comment: Might be useful for us to see your way of computing the integration factor $\mu$ to see if you have done any mistakes.

Comment: @stange Added the solution process.

Comment: Your integration factor is wrong. When you integrate $\frac{-2x}{x-1}$ the result is $-2\ln(x-1)-2x$, not $-2x+2-2\ln(x-1)$.

Comment: How so? If you integrate applying the $u$ substitution , you get $u= x-1 , x=u+1 , du=dx$ and from there you integrate by u $ \int{1+1/u}  $ and from there you get $u+lnu$ and then $x-1+ln(x-1) $ and you multiply it by $-2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your integration factor *does* make your ODE exact.

Let $$f(x, y) = \frac{e^{-2x+2} (2xy-y^2+2y)}{2(x-1)}.$$

You can easily verify that
$$ \begin{cases} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \mu(x) M(x, y) \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \mu(x) N(x, y)\end{cases} .$$

Thus $$df = \mu(x) M(x, y) dx + \mu(x) N(x, y) dy.$$

---

If you're wondering how I came up with this $f(x, y)$, I'll tell you what I did.

I needed to find an $f(x, y)$ such that
$$ \begin{cases} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \mu(x) M(x, y) \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) = \mu(x) N(x, y)\end{cases} .$$

Integrating the first equation on both sides w.r.t. $x$, I found that this $f(x,y)$ must satisfy
$$ f(x, y) = \int dx \ \mu(x) M(x, y) = \frac{e^{-2x+2} (2xy-y^2+2y)}{2(x-1)} + a(y), \qquad \qquad (\star)$$
where $a(y)$ is some function of $y$. (This $a(y)$ is the "constant of integration" that we always have to add on when we calculate an indefinite integral. But here, our integrand is a function of $y$ as well as $x$, so the "constant of integration" is not constant, but rather, a function of $y$.)

Integrating the second equation on both sides w.r.t $y$, I found that this $f(x, y)$ must also satisfy
$$ f(x, y) = \int dy \ \mu(x) M(x, y) = \frac{e^{-2x+2} (2xy-y^2+2y)}{2(x-1)} + b(x), \qquad \qquad (\dagger) $$
where $b(x)$ is some function of $x$.

Then I noticed that I could satisfy both $(\star)$ and $(\dagger)$ by taking $a(y) = 0$ and $b(x) = 0$. And that's how I came up with this $f(x, y)$.

---

Now let's relate this observation to your ODE. Your ODE is
$$ M(x,y)dx + N(x, y)dy = 0,$$
which, upon multiplying both sides by $\mu(x)$, is equivalent to
$$ \mu(x) M(x, y) dx + \mu(x) N(x, y) dy = 0.$$
But we know that $df = \mu(x) M(x, y) dx + \mu(x) N(x, y) dy$, so in fact, your ODE is equivalent to
$$ df = 0.$$
Thus, the solution to your ODE is $$f(x, y) = c,$$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Ty for the answer. I don't understand how from multiplying the original ODE - you got to $f(x,y)$ . Sorry if that sounds dumb , but I'm just beginning with ODE's.

Comment: @Him Does this edit help?

Comment: First of all that edit helps a lot understanding the whole solution  . Thank you very much! So in (⋆) you integrated  the equation , $ \mu(x) M(x,y)dx $ which equals $\frac{e^{-2x+2}}{(x-1)^2} * (-2x^2y+xy^2-0.5y^2)$  ? And same way goes for $\mu(x)N(x,y)$ ? So where does the a(y) and b(x) come from?

Comment: That's right. See my latest edit about a(y) and b(x)

Comment: Thanks again. I still don't understand how $ \int{\frac{e^{-2x+2}}{(x-1)^2} *(-2x^2y+xy^2-0.5y^2)} = \frac{e^{-2x+2}(2xy-y^2+2y)}{2(x-1)} +a(y) $ . I think I don't have the knowledge to solve that kind of integration yet(In my solution I'm allowed to leave it as an implicit function but as you said the final solution is $f(x,y)$ = c).

Comment: One way to check that the integral is correct is to differentiate my answer and see if it gives back the integrand.

Comment: That's what I did just now. You get $f_y=f_x$ which means I get an exact ODE. I just don't get how to get the original $f(x,y)$ which as I said I don't think I have the tools to get to(like in (⋆).

Comment: I gave the integrals to Wolfram Alpha, and then I checked that the answers were correct by differentiating. Why didn't you try that?

Comment: I used Symolab and didn't get an answer. Didn't know about Wolfarm Alpha. Anyway , thanks for the help it's all clear now!